# Does AndroidDriver node have to be on same machine as the hub?

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

When following the instructions to set up [AndroidDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver) (page seems to be down temporarily), it is not entirely clear how the driver is being attached to the hub and whether I can attach it to a remote hub.

After installing web driver on the Android emulator/device, there are these instructions:

> You can start the application in debug mode, which has more verbose
>   logs by doing:
>
> $./adb -s  shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n
>   org.openqa.selenium.android.app/.MainActivity -e debug true Now we
>   need to setup the port forwarding in order to forward traffic from the
>   host machine to the emulator. In a terminal type:
>
> $./adb -s  forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080
>
> This will make the android server available at
>   localhost:8080/wd/hub from the host machine. You're now ready
>   to run the tests. Let's take a look at some code.

But what if want to make the server available at remoteHub:8080/wd/hub instead?

Can I attach my `AndroidDriver` node to a remote hub? Or does it have to be on or attached to the same machine as the hub?

**Edit**: If I try to point my AndroidDriver at the remote hub:

```
AndroidDriver androidDriver = new AndroidDriver(new Uri("remote...:4444/wd/hub"));
Drivers.Add(androidDriver);
```

I get the following `InvalidOperationException`:

> Error forwarding the new session cannot find : {platform=ANDROID,
>   browserName=android, rotatable=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=}